# Prove such finite real function's range is a finite set or countable set

Tags: real-analysis

Let function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be finite and satisfies the following condition:
$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \exists \delta_x > 0, s.t. \forall y\in (x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x),f(y)\geq f(x)
$$
Prove that the range of $f(x)$, $f(\mathbb{R})$ is a finite set or countable set.

---

Here is a solution from a textbook. For each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we can find $r_1(x),r_2(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$, s.t. $x\in (r_1(x),r_2(x)) \subset (x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)$. Collect all these intervals into a set $\mathcal{A}_f = \{(r_1(x),r_2(x)):x\in \mathbb{R} \}$. We readily have $\mathcal{A}_f \subset \mathbb{Q}^2$ and thus $\mathcal{A}_f$ is at most countable. Then it claims that on each interval in $\mathcal{A}_f$, $f(x)$ is constant. Then with the countability of $\mathcal{A}_f$ we know that the range of $f(x)$ is at most countable.

My question is how to prove that $f(x)$ is contant on each interval in $\mathcal{A}_f$? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true that $f$ is constant on intervals from $A_f$ (and it would imply that $f$ is just constant, as such intervals overlap).

We can show another property: if $(r_1(x), r_2(x)) = (r_1(y), r_2(y))$ then $f(x) = f(y)$. Indeed, from definition of $r_1$ and $r_2$, $x, y \in (r_1(x), r_2(x))$. And $y \in (r_1(x), r_2(x))$ implies $f(y) \geq f(x)$, similarly we have $f(x) \geq f(y)$, thus $f(x) = f(y)$.

So, if $f$ has different values in two points, this two points correspond to different intervals. Thus $f$ has at most countable different values (as each unique value corresponds to it's own interval from countable set).

Comment: Thanks, now I see the point. You basically construct an injection from $f(R)$ to $A_f$. Then with Bernstein's theorem, we know the cardinality of $f(R)$ is less than or equal to the cardinality of $A_f$, which is a countable set.